# Facebook Topic Search API not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to build an application which needs to search in public Facebook posts.

As I search for solution I found the Topic Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/topic_search/v2.4

I tried this API using a Facebook Application but getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

How can I gain access to use the search API?

Comment: Can you share with us how do you call your service?

Comment: Thanks #Metehan for your quick response. Before using it in my application. I'm testing it in Graph API Explorer using my App Token.

 /search?type=topic&q=lebron james&fields=id,name,page

Comment: Okay, OAuthException means authentication exception. In Facebook Graph API some endpoints are public and some endpoints require authentication. Authentication means you sign in to Facebook and it returns you oauthtoken. You use that token inside the your query.

Comment: I tried it using user's token which needs user Authentication. But it says..

    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app     access_token.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 15
      }
}

So, I used the APP token.

Comment: Your url has to be like : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/search?access_token=...&client_secret=...type=topic&q=lebron%20james&fields=id,name,page . If you still get exception, your client_secret or access_token must be wrong.

Comment: Yes..  graph.facebook.com/v2.4/ is automatically prepended in Graph API Explorer..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83335/discussion-between-sukanta-paul-and-metehan-toksoy).

Comment: Topic search API is available for use, only to manually selected companies who are further said to be partners of Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this is not a public API (which should be documented by FB), so this means that you cannot use this with your own apps. I guess specific app_ids from partners are actively whitelisted.

Comment: Okay, if it is not public. Then what is the procedure to get authentication. Or if any partner can give access. Then, how is that possible?

Comment: @SukantaPaul: I don’t think you can apply for direct access at this time. If you want to use it, you have to work with one of the partners listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mediasolutions/partners